# Jcrop FabricJS image object: move/scale limit

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs, jcrop

I'm doing crop image object on FabrijcJS.
Here I am using Jcrop, but I have a problem is when I move/scale crop designated areas, it is moved out of the active object.
Please help me one solution: crop frame only move inside the active object

[image]

```
    var object = canvas.getActiveObject();

    function updatePreview(c) {
        if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
        }
    }

    $('#c').Jcrop({
        onSelect: updatePreview,
        onChange: updatePreview,
        allowSelect: false,
        allowMove: false,
        allowResize: true,
        setSelect: [object.left, object.top, object.left + object.width * object.scaleX, object.top + object.height * object.scaleY],
        aspectRatio: 0,
        minSize: [1, 1],
        maxSize: [object.width * object.scaleX, object.height * object.scaleY]
    });
```

Comment: when you move the crop area, does 'object:moving' event of canvas fires?

Comment: I think 'object:moving' is event of Fabricjs(Canvas), not of Jcrop crop area

Comment: Yes 'object:moving' is event of Fabricjs(Canvas),

Comment: maybe a little fiddle could help